# Upload 'custom dimensions' data to google analytics

Tags: google-analytics, google-tag-manager

Consider the Following scenario:

I have following custom attributes configured in the GA,

1. `Session_Uid`
2. `XYZ`

When customer visits the website I am adding `Session_Uid` (say: `Session_Uid`:4352 )in the 'dataLayer' so that it will be added to custom dimensions of GA.

Calculation logic for `XYZ` attribute is not real time. So I am taking required parameters to the server and calculating `XYZ` attribute offline.

Now, after calculating `XYZ` attribute I want to map the `XYZ` attribute to the hit data where `Session_Uid`  is '4352'.

Is it possible to achieve this scenario?

I have tried the 'Data Import' option of GA with key attribute as 'Session_Uid' but it did not work.

Answer (score 0):

My educated guess would be that XYZ is a hit scoped custom dimension. Dimension widening via data import only works for dimensions within the same scope. If you cannot turn XYZ into a session scoped dimension it might help to duplicate Session_Uid into a hit scoped dimension.

Comment: Thanks for the comment. Both custom dimensions are having same scope (ie ``session`` scope), The Key question is, Can recorded data by GA be updated using Data import option in GA?

Comment: Yes, that's possible (not with all data set types, but at least with user data, content data and obviously content data).